# jQuery functions not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have two jQuery functions one for date time picker

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {         
        $("#txtDate").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

And another for Multiselect Dropdown/Listbox with checkbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[id*=lstFruits]').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
    });
```

And the ASP code as:

for date time

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

for dropdown

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstFruits" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Mango" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Apple" Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Banana" Value="3" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Guava" Value="4" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Orange" Value="5" />
</asp:ListBox>
```

The problem that I am having is that both of them don't work together if I put them in my code only date time picker works and not the multi-select dropdown and the multi-select dropdown works only when I comment out the corresponding date time picker code.

There is some dysfunctionality which I am not able to figure out.

Comment: What errors are thrown in browser console? Note that script tag for `multiselect` as shown has a missing `>`. Can see problem in syntax highlighting in the question code

Comment: Also any chance you are including jQuery.js more than once?

Comment: yeah i think there was some collapse in the included jQuery.js files.  The below code is working fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working sample based on the files you are referencing in your page put it is HTML based not ASPX it will be easy to you to use.

Note:- you were referencing two jquery versions i commented one of them

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>!-->
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txtDate").datepicker();
    $('[id*=lstFruits]').multiselect({
      includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
  });
</script>
```

Please find the full sample [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/V34nWgodjOq15PtH0sRr?p=preview)

Comment: You are welcome any time Please Vote up and  mark as answer @Rahul

Comment: Mark as answer Please.